# 'insufficient access rights on object id'

Tags: permissions, user-management, role-hierarchy

One of my users is trying to update a Contact record. OWD is Public Read Only on Contact. Grant access using hierarchy is checked. The user sits higher in the role hierarchy than the record owner. The user's profile has Create, Read, Edit, View All perm on Contact object. 'Insufficient access rights on object id' error shows up when that user is trying to edit a record. I am ruling out problems relating to other related objects because when I add that user to a Modify All Perm set for Contact for testing purposes, that user IS able to edit that record. Of course we do NOT want to grant that user that access. What am I missing?

Comment: To add, it's only unique to that one user. Other users with same profile and same role hierarchy do not have the same issue.

Comment: so, use the Sharing button on the Contact and compare for this user versus the other users. There could be apex managed sharing or criteria-based sharing in play here that explains the difference

Comment: Check if you are not updating any related record via apex trigger etc, that you might have miss access.